# How to get events from public pages? (with example)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display the public events from public pages, I've been researching a lot and even requested the "Page Public Content Access" but they say to get just the events it's not "enough" for them to give access.

They recommend using mange_pages (but this requires the admin of the page to give permission, and this is not what I'm looking for)

I have seen websites that display events of public pages (from facebook) for example:

https://allevents.in/org/uncle-alberts-pub/6779766

Does anyone knows how I can accomplish this without having to ask for permission and maybe just using the page_id?

Answer (score 1):

I´m afraid there are only 2 ways:

- Get a Page Token of the Page with `manage_pages` and use it for the API call - you can only do that if you manage the Page
- Get approved for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) by Facebook and use a simple App Token for the API call

There is no other way.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of this, and I don't know why Facebook doesn't wanna approve my app for Page Public Content Access because they say it's not enough just use to events :/ .. thank you for your answer!